# If Button1.Click = true

Tags: delphi

```
Button1: TButton; 
Label2: TLabel;

procedure TForm5.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
 begin 
 if Button1.Click = True then
      Label2.Caption := 'lol';
```

Basically what I want is that, when user clicks on the button, Label2 changes what's written there. Yes I do have Label2.
The error that's coming out is "**E2008 Incompatible types**"...
 Can anyone help me out here?

Comment: How can your code even compile? `TButton` does not have any Method or Property named `Click`. But if you thought about `Button1.OnClick` then this would indeed return that error since `Button1.OnClick` is a reference to the Event Method of `OnClick` event and not a `Boolean` value. As for how do you achieve the desired check the @kot-da-vinci answer bellow.

Comment: @SilverWarior http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE7/en/Vcl.StdCtrls.TCustomButton.Click    ...that said, this question is unlikely to be useful to anyone in the future.  Any tutorial whatsoever...chapter 1, page1.  That would have solved this.  Incidentally, calling `Button1.Click` inside its own `OnClick` handler will generate an infinite loop... 0_o

Comment: Ups my mistake. I checked the documentation to quickly and inefficiently.

Answer (score 8):

Method `Click` is not a function and it has no return value. So you can't compare it with `True`.
Your `Button1Click` is event handler of your `Button1` click event. When user clicks on the `Button1` code in `Button1Click` executes. So you need to write your `Button1Click` like this:

```
procedure TForm5.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin 
  Label2.Caption := 'lol';
end;
```